If $Y\to X$ is a birational morphism of normal projective algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ and $X$ is smooth, is $Y$ smooth too?
Let $Y\to X$ be a projective birational morphism between normal projective algebraic varieties over $\mathbb{C}$. Further, suppose that $X$ is smooth. Does it then follow that $Y$ is smooth as well?
Note that this holds trivially for $\dim Y=1$, and also for $\dim Y=2$: in this latter case, we can resolve $Y$ to obtain a diagram $Z\to Y\to X$ where both $X$ and $Z$ are smooth. Therefore, the composition $Z\to X$ is a birational map between smooth projective surfaces, and thus a sequence of blow-ups of points. Hence the exceptional locus of $Z\to X$ is a forest of $(-1)$-curves, and furthermore it contains the exceptional locus of $Z\to Y$. Hence the latter is a forest of $(-1)$-curves as well, and thus by Castelnuovo's contractibility criterion, $Y$ must be smooth.
Can one generalize this argument to higher dimensions? One could still take a resoultion $Z\to Y$, and then one might apply the weak factorization theorem to $Z\to X$. However, I fail to see how to deduce meaningful information about $Y$ from this, as the picture is much more complicated in higher dimensions.

In fact, this is not true even in the case of surfaces. The simplest counterexample is the following. Let $Z$ be obtained from $X$ by blowing up a point and then blowing up another point on the exceptional divisor of the first blowup. If $E_1 \subset Z$ is the strict transform of the exceptional divisor of the first blowup then $E_1$ is a $(-2)$-curve. Let $Y$ be obtained by contracting $E_1$. Then $Y$ is a surface with one node (the image of $E_1$) that has a birational morphism to $X$.
Alternatively, $Y$ can be obtained as the blowup of a subscheme
$$
\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2) \subset X.
$$
